# The sequence of distances of a sequence with no limit from a compact set converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $U \subset X$ is an open set such that $X- U$ is compact, where $X-U:=\{x \in X: x \notin U\}$. Let $A \subset U$ is a countable infinite subset of $U$ such that $A$ has no limit point in $U$ and let us assume $A=\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$. Since $X-U$ is compact, we can find a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset X-U$ such that
$$d(a_n,b_n) \leq d(a_n,b),~~\text{ for all } b \in X-U.$$
Now consider the sequence $\{\gamma_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of positive real numbers defined by
$$\gamma_n=d(a_n,b_n),~~\text{ for } n \ge 1.$$
Now prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n=0.$

Now to prove this, I decide to assume the contradict path that let $\lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n=L$ where $L\neq 0$ then show that $A$ has a limit point. But I am not able to show this.
Can you please help me to solve this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: $\ \gamma_n \to \infty,\ $ not $\ 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X= \mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean metric and $U := \{x|\, |x|>1\}$ the complement of the unit disc. Then let $a_n = (n+1, 0) $ a sequence of points on the $x$-axis which goes off to infinity $(n\ge1)$.

Then, clearly, $b_n= (1,0) $ for every $n$, and it also not difficult to see that then  $\gamma_n =n\rightarrow \infty \neq 0$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, +1. By the way, sir is it true if we assume $X$ to be a compact metric space, instead of simply "metric space"?

Comment: @abcdmath If $X$ itself is compact, then the statement is vacuous. Every inifinite subset $A$ **must** have a limit point.

Comment: @ayeayemaung yes sir, in that case A must have a limit point in X, but may not be in U (I think). So in that case is it true that the sequence $\{\gamma_n\}$ goes to 0? I did mistake while typing my question that, $A$ has no limit point in $U$.

Comment: @abcdmath Even then, you can still find counterexamples where $a_n$ "oscillates back and forth". I think this works: think of my example with all the spaces restricted to $[-3, 3]$ (therefore getting compactness) but now consider $a_n = 1 + (n \mod 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove that in general. Here is a counterexample. Let $X = \Bbb R$ with the standard metric. Let $U = (-\infty, -1) \cup (0, \infty)$ so that $X - U = [-1, 0]$ is compact. Let $A = (n)_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq U$, which has no limit points obviously.

Now clearly $(b_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ given by $b_n = 0$ is a sequence in $X - U$ such that
$$
d(a_n, b_n) = n \leq n + |b| = d(a_n, b) \quad \forall b \in X - U
$$ But $\gamma_n = d(a_n, b_n) = n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $A \subset U$ is a countable infinite subset of $U$ such that $A$
> has no limit point...

This is only true if $\ U\ $ is unbounded, which should have been one of the assumptions - that is, your first sentence should have been, "Suppose $\ U\ $ is an unbounded open subset of $\ X\ $ such that $\ X \setminus U\ $ is compact". I will continue assuming this is what was meant.

I agree that you can do the construction with $\ a_n\ $ and $\ b_n,\ $ but $\ \gamma_n \to\infty,\ $ not $\ 0.\ $ To see this, let $\ b\in X\setminus U,\ $ and consider the fact that  $\ A=\{a_n\}_n\ $ has no limit points, and is therefore unbounded by Bolzano-Weierstrass. That is, given $\ M\in\ \mathbb{R},\  \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ d(b, a_n) > M\ \forall\ n\geq N.\ $ Since $\ b\ $ was arbitrary and $\ X\setminus U\ $ is bounded, it is not difficult to see that $\ \gamma_n\to 0,\ $ although I will leave the details as an exercise to the reader, although as a hint, you could consider when $\ b=b_n.\ $ or you could use the triangle inequality and involve $\ \text{diam}( X\setminus U ).$